# Knime Batchmode : Java returned exit code 4

Tags: java, batch-file, exit-code, knime

I invoked a Knime Batch from my java application, but he returns always this one: [Knime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRb9x.png)
I try to find something that could help me, but i don't get it. 
So it's a problem about different Java types 64 bit and 32 bit ? 
Thank you for help.

Error Message

```
    Java was started but returndes exit code =4 
    -server
    -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
    -Dosgi.classloader.lock = classname 
    -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
    -XX:+UnsyncloadClass 
    -Dknime.enable.fastload=true 
    -XX.CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot
    -Xmx512m
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
    -Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true
-Djava.class.path=E:\KNIME\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar 

    -os win32 
    -ws win32
    -arch x86 
    -showsplash
    -launcher E:\KNIM\knime.exe
    -name Knime 
    -launcher libary
    E:\KNIME\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.300.v20150602-1417\eclipse_1611.dll

    -startup
    -E:\KNIME\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar 
-launcher.overrideVmargs
-application org.knime.product.KNIME_BATCH_APPLICATION
-workflowFile=C:\myFile.zip
-vm E:\KNIME\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-server
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
-Dosgi.classloader.lock=classname
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions 
-XX:+UnsyncloadClass 
-Dknime.enable.fastload=true 
-XX.CompileCommand=exclude,javax/swing/text/GlyphView,getBreakSpot
-Xmx512m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
-Dsun.awt.noerasebackground=true
-Djava.class.path=E:\KNIME\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

Comment: Error messages are text. Please don't post text in a screenshot, or a link to a screenshot: post the text into your question.

Comment: Okay, i start writing the error message, i can't copy this . And know i have to use Code editing for that.

Comment: Take a look at this and see if it helps at all: https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-users/knime-run-from-command-line-under-dos-can-it-block-and-return-cleanly.

Comment: Are you sure the tag batch-file is appropriate here, as it is used for .bat files and not for batch execution, please look at this for more information: [batch-files](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/info)

Comment: i used the Knime Batch mode

Comment: What command did you use to execute KNIME headless?

Answer (score 0):

It means there's an error in your workflow. Expand the .zip file into a directory and use the -workflowDir option to execute it. From there you can execute KNIME in headless mode and if/when there's an error, you'll be able to re-open the workflow in normal KNIME and see the node that is giving you the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late the response but just in case someone finds this post.

Knime has a mechanism to lock the workflow while its running. So you can't run multiple instances simultaneously of the same workflow.

In order to run a knime workflow, you need to export it. Save it as a zip file and run it with the the option workflowFile instead of workflowDir. More info [here](https://www.knime.com/faq#q12)